# How do I know if a variable name is used on any package

Tags: python

I'm writing Python code in Visual Studio 2017.

Sometimes I make a variable name, and the debugger breaks, because the variable name is already used inside some package, or even as a package name (for example, the variable "re" is used as a package name for  regular expressions.

The debugger stops working without any warning.

I get no message about the use of duplicated names.

How do I check that a variable name is non used anywhere?

Comment: You absolutely don't need to know what variables are used in packages. Even using `re` as a variable is not an error on its own. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: @Lev Levitsky using "re" as variable is not an error, but VS debugger stops working, so I need to check if "re" is available each time I create a new variable.

Comment: That sounds like an _awful_ user experience.  I'd file a bug report w/ MS (if you have the means to do so).  As far as how you can know, definitively, whether something is a module or not ... well ... you can't.  You can open a shell somewhere and try to import every variable name you want to create before you use it in your code, but that's a horrible strategy.